# How do I align <div> elements so that they are centered with one another and resemble a target in css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a target out of div elements but I cannot seem to figure out how to align them so that they are all centered and the smallest of the div elements is visible on top.  In the html file all I have are div elements since I am doing all of the modifications in the CSS file. It should look something like this but with different colours.[Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0koWd.png)

```css
/* box_model.css */
div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    position:absolute;
}
div:nth-of-type(2) {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
div:nth-of-type(3) {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-radius: 80px;
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

div:nth-of-type(4) {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you had a picture of what you are trying to create.

Answer (score 1):

First, I gave the parent container (in your case, `body`), a `flex` display. Next, I made all children absolutely positioning, so that they can stack on top of one another using `z-index`. Finally, the vertical `transform` was added to account for their own height, so that the elements would be truly positioned in the center of the screen.

**Note:** I condensed all the `border-radius` lines into a single line, to hopefully make your life a bit easier.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

body>div {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  z-index: 4;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: 3;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 2;
}

div:nth-of-type(4) {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Result:

[image]

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/waLbudkq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want to accomplish. This is your CSS code:

```
div.red {
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   background-color: red;
   border-radius: 50px;
   display:flex;
   align-items: center;
   position:absolute;
   z-index: 3;
}
div.orange {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
div.yellow {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 80px;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

div.green {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

And this is you HTML code:

```
<div class="green">
  <div class="orange"></div>
  <div class="yellow"></div>
  <div class="red"></div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#a1{
    display:flex;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 125px;
    z-index:5;
   justify-content:center;
   align-items:center;
}
#a2{
    display:flex;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-radius: 100px;
    z-index:10;
   justify-content:center;
   align-items:center;
}

#a3{
    display:flex;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 75px;
    z-index:15;
   justify-content:center;
   align-items:center;
}

#a4{
    display:flex;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50px;
    z-index:20;
   justify-content:center;
   align-items:center;
}
   
   
use flexbox with z-index
```

```html
<div id='a1'>
<div id='a2'>
<div id='a3'>
<div id='a4'></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few techniques you might want to to use here.

Firstly, [`absolute` positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) lets you position an object relative to its parents layout.

Remember that `absolute` positioned elements are positioned based on *the next parent that has absolute or relative positioning*. That is, if the immediate parent has `position: static` that parent will be ignored for the purpose of absolute positioning. This is why, in my example, I've given the container div `position: relative` - just to make the absolute positioning apply.

Secondly, the [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function lets you make derived calculations - in this case to perfectly center things, we calc the `left` and `right` properties as `50% of the parent's width, minus 1/2 * however wide we want this thing to be`.

Thirdly, the `z-index` property lets us control how which element displays on top.

I've quickly modified what you've done, and here's what I've got.

```css
/* box_model.css */

.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px; 
}

.container>.target {
    position:absolute;
}
.target:nth-of-type(1) {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50px;
    z-index: 4; 
    left: calc(50% - 25px); 
    top: calc(50% - 25px); 
}

.target:nth-of-type(2) {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 50px;
    z-index: 3; 
    left: calc(50% - 50px); 
    top: calc(50% - 50px); 


}
.target:nth-of-type(3) {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-radius: 80px;
    z-index:2; 
    left: calc(50% - 75px); 
    top: calc(50% - 75px); 
}

.target:nth-of-type(4) {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 150px;
    z-index:1; 
    left: calc(50% - 125px); 
    top: calc(50% - 125px); 

}
```

```html
<div class = "container"> 
   <div class ="target"></div>
   <div class ="target"></div>
   <div class ="target"></div>
   <div class ="target"></div>
</div>
```

I would note though - that generally manually setting z-index values should be avoided, because as your application grows you might find other things over lapping when you don't want them to.

Instead, you can control how the elements stack just by their document position - in this case - make the largest circle the first element, rather than the last.

Answer (score 0):

I hope This help

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(1) {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top:calc(50% - 150px);
  left: calc(50% - 150px);
}
.wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top:calc(50% - 100px);
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
}
.wrapper div:nth-child(3) {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top:calc(50% - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```